# Antlr and PL/I grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Right now we would like to have the grammar of PL/I, COBOL based on Antlr4. Is there anyone provide these grammars
If not, can you please share your thought/experience on developing these grammars from scratch
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean IBM PL/I and COBOL. (Not many other PL/Is around, but I don't think that really changes the answer much).

The obvious place to look for mature ANTLR grammars is [ANTLR3 grammar library](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html); no PL/1 or COBOL grammars there.  The Antlr V4 (a very new, radical, backwards incompatible reengineering of ANTLR3) main page talks about Java and C#; no hint of PL/1 or COBOL there; given its newness, no surprise.  If you are really lucky, somebody may have one they will give you and speak up.

Developing such grammars is difficult for several reasons (based on personal experience building production-quality parsers for these two specific items, using a very strong parser system different than ANTLR [see my bio for more details]):

- The character set and column layout rules (columns 1-5, 6 and 72-80 are special) may be an issue: the languages you describe are typically written in EBCDIC historically in punch-card 80 column format without line break characters between lines.  Translation to ASCII sometimes produces nasty glitches; the ASCII end-of-line character is occasionally found in the middle of COBOL literal strings as a binary value, but because it has the *same* exact code in EBCDIC and ASCII, after translation it will (be and) appear to be an ASCII newline break character. Character strings can also be long but split across multiple lines; but columns 72-80 by definition have to be ignored.  Column 6 may contain a "D" character, which affects interpretation of the following source lines as "debug" or "not".    This means you need to get 80 column processing right.  I don't know what ANTLR has to support processing characters-in-column-areas.  You'll also need to worry about DBCS encoding of string literals, and variations of that if the source code is used in non-English speaking countries, such as Japan.
- These languages are large and complex; IBM has had 40 years to decorate them with cruft.  The IBM COBOL manual is some 600 pages ... then you discover that COBOL also includes a Report Writer, which is *another* 600 page document.  Capturing all the nuances of the lexical tokens and the grammar rules will take effort, and you have to do that from the IBM manuals, which don't contain nice BNF-style descriptions, which means guessing from the textual description and some examples.  For COBOL, expect several thousand grammar rules; PL/1 is less complicated in the abstract. Expect a certain amount of "lies"; we've encountered a number of places where the reference documentation clearly says certain things are not legal, and yet the IBM compilers (based on real, running source code) accepts them, and vice versa.  The only way you find these is by empirical experiments.
- Both languages have constructs that are difficult to parse, e.g., requiring arbitrary lookahead and/or local ambiguity.  ANTLR4 is much better than ANTLR3 from my understanding on these, but that doesn't mean these aspects will be easy.   PL/1 is particularly nasty in this regard: it has no keywords, but hundreds of keywords-in-context.  To resolve these one has to get the lexer and the parser to cooperate, and even then there may be many locally ambiguous parses.  ANTLR3 doesn't do these well;  ANTLR4 is supposed to be better but I don't know how it handles this, if it does at all.
- To verify these parsers are right, you will need to run them on millions of lines of code (which means  you have to have access to such code samples), and correct any errors you find.   This takes a long time (in our case, several years of more or less continuous work/improvement to get production quality grammars that work on large code bases).  You might be miraculously faster than this; good luck.
- You need to build a preprocessor for COBOL (COPY ... REPLACING), whose details are poorly documented, and eventually another one for PL/1 (which I understand to be fully Turing capable).
- After you build a parser, you need to capture a syntax tree; here ANTLR4 is supposed to be pretty good in that it will capture one for the grammar  you give it.  That may or may not be the AST you want; with several thousand grammar rules, I'd expect not.  ANTLR3 requires you to add, manually, indications of where and how to form the AST.

After you get the AST, you'll want to do something with it.  This means you will need to build at least symbol tables (mappings from identifier instances to their declarations and any related type information).  ANTLR provides nothing special to support this AFAIK except for support in walking the ASTs.   This, too, is hard to get right, COBOL has crazy rules about how an unqualified identifier reference can be interpreted as to a specific data field if there are no other conflicting interpretations. (There's lots more to Life After Parsing if you want to have good semantic information about the program; see my bio for more details; for each of these semantic aspects you have develop them and then for validation go back and run them on large code bases again.).

TL;DR

Building parsers (well, "front ends") for these languages is a *lot* of work no matter what parsing engine you choose.   Likely explains why they aren't already in ANTLR's grammar zoo.

Comment: Bad news is better than no news... Thank you

Comment: Now there is another place for mature ANTLR grammars https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. But it still does not contain the grammar for PL/I.

Comment: I doubt the issues that PL/1 raises (esp. re "no keywords") have been resolved in ANTLR4, which means it is pretty unlikely that ANTLR4 will *ever* have a full Pl/1 parser.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the **OpenSource** Cobol-85 Parser from ProLeap, based on antlr4 and creating ASTs and ASGs as well.
And, best of all, it really works !

https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser

I am not aware of a comparable PLI-grammar, but a very good start is the EBNF-definition from  Ralf Lämmel (CWI, Amsterdam) & Chris Verhoef (WINS, Universiteit van Amsterdam) 
http://www.cs.vu.nl/grammarware/browsable/os-pli-v2r3/